# How to Invoke Stanford NLP API over internet

Tags: amazon-ec2, stanford-nlp

I have installed and started Stanford CoreNLP on AWS using this

```
java -mx4g -cp "*" edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLPServer -port 9000 -timeout 15000
```

This works on localhost

```
wget --post-data 'The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog.' 'localhost:9000/?properties={"annotators":"tokenize,ssplit,pos","outputFormat":"json"}' -O -
```

But when i call from a different terminal, using the External IP instead of localhost, client keeps looping.

```
 wget --post-data 'The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog.' '13.126.58.85:9000/?properties={"annotators":"tokenize,ssplit,pos","outputFormat":"json"}' -O -
```

This is the message in client as it keeps trying......

```
--2018-09-10 17:01:44--  http://13.126.58.85:9000/?properties=%7B%22annotators%22:%22tokenize,ssplit,pos%22,%22outputFormat%22:%22json%22%7D
Connecting to 13.126.58.85:9000...
```

Any idea what could be issue ?

Comment: Does your firewall allow you to connect out to that URL on that port?  It could be blocking you.

Comment: @duffymo Will check. New to ubuntu.

Comment: Me, too.  Maybe this will help you: https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/serverguide/firewall.html.en

Comment: And this: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/UncomplicatedFirewall

Comment: @duffymo sudo enable ufw; sudo allow 9000; But no change

Comment: Must be something else, then.  Sorry.

Comment: @duffymo I realized i had not allowed HTTP in AWS. Checking that.